# Docker compose with Spring Boot Applications

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two images- caller and callable.

When using docker compose and hitting the url of callable from caller image container, it is not working.

My docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  callerc:
    image: caller:1.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8084"
    environment:
      - URL=callmec/callMe
  callmec:
    image: callable:1.0
    ports:
      - "5000:8082"
```

I get URI not absolute. When i try URL parameter as - http://callmec/callMe" then also it doens't work and says Connection refused.
*But when I give the URL as my Machine IPv4 address - http://172.XX.XX.XX:5000/callMe then it works.*

While trying "localhost:8000/callOtherService" gave Connection refused error - "callmec:5000/callMe": Connection refused

Kindly guide in case I have missed something.

Comment: It is not clear, what are you asking. Do you want to access the container from docker's host machine or from the other container of the stack(`callerc`)? In both cases, it seems you are missing the port from the url.

Comment: Added port number for and it worked but connecting via 172.XX.XX.XX:5000/callMe BUT while trying "http://localhost:8000/callOtherService" gave Connection refused error - "http://callmec:5000/callMe": Connection refused

Comment: Putting URL=http://callmec:8082/callMe worked

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the port when you reference the container :  `http://callmec/callMe`.
It uses the default HTTP port (80) such as `http://callmec:80/callMe`.
But no socket appears to listen that port on the `callmec` container.
What you want is :  `http://callmec:8082/callMe`

Comment: He said that with the IP of the docker host it works so it's not a port problme

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I know but it makes no sense that it works on the host in that way.  In my answer, I focused on the way of requesting in HTTP an application on a container.

Comment: Whatever, the question is unclear. Not sure that answering to that is a good idea.

Comment: http://172.XX.XX.XX:5000/callMe - It works like this ...
i will try giving the port number http://callmec:5000/callMe as well...

Comment: While trying "localhost:8000/callOtherService" gave Connection refused error - "callmec:5000/callMe": Connection refused

Comment: Putting URL=http://callmec:8082/callMe worked...

Thanks davidxxx

Comment: @SimonMartinelli u should show little patience as well for the beginners...
any ways thanks for the support from you two.

Answer (score 0):

callmec is not a name entry for 172.XX.XX.XX

If you want to use a local name for the Docker IP 172.XX.XX.XX then you have to add it to your hosts file:

On Linux you have to modify the /etc/hosts file.

Please read this document to see how you must do it on other OS: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/